# Binding with WPF ComboBox

Tags: wpf

[image]I had used combo box which name is cmbTobetraced  in my code to select Yes or no value but I am not able to bind the data to combo box.Its not showing "No " value in combo box Text .Its always shows yes value. I had checked with SelectedItem and  SelectedItem but also not showing results .Tobetraced is a property name which is string data type in my class :

```
...
<GridViewColumn Header="To be traced" Width="Auto">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox  
                       Width="60"     
                       Name="cmbTobetraced"     
                       Margin="0,15,0,5"    
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                       BorderBrush="White"      
                       SelectedValuePath="Tag"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Tobetraced, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Yes" Tag="0"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="No" Tag="1" />
                <!--<ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath>
                <Binding Path="Tobetraced"  />
                </ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath>-->
                <!--<ComboBoxItem  >Yes</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >No</ComboBoxItem>-->
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
<GridViewColumn Header="View Panel Trace Details " Width="Auto">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  Width="Auto"> 
                <Hyperlink Foreground="White" 
                           Click="buttonClose_Click" 
                           Cursor="Hand">View Panel Trace</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
</GridView.Columns>
</GridView>
</ListView.View>
</ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Post your code for the Property "Tobetraced" which your Binding to. The Xaml itself is not enough to tell wheres the problem. And maybe you can cut down your xaml to the relevant code!

Comment: Hi, we can't tell what's wrong unless you show us "Tobetraced" which I assume is a datamodel. We do not know your datacontext either. You are adding your items to your cbox manually, setting content to string, while at the same time you are binding the cbox to a property(assuming) on your datamodel(assuming again :). Avoid doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a few problems with your XAML. `SelectedValuePath` will not work with the design approach that you are using. I think what you really need to bind is the `SelectedItem` property.

The concept of `SelectedItem`, `SelecteValuePath`, and `SelectedValue` is exhaustively explained in the MSDN web references - I strongly suggest that you become deeply familiar with  the concept. One reference that you might want to start off on is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788714(v=vs.110).aspx

You might bind to `SelectedItem` like this:

```
<ComboBox  
     Width="60"     
     Name="cmbTobetraced"     
     Margin="0,15,0,5"    
     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
     VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
     BorderBrush="White"      
     SelectedItem="SelectedAnswer"
     Text="{Binding Path=Tobetraced, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

The code-behind might look like this:

```
    private string selectedAnswer;
    public object SelectedAnswer
    {
        get { return selectedAnswer; }
        set
        {
            var cboItem = value as ComboBoxItem;
            if (cboItem == null) return;

            selectedAnswer = cboItem.Content.ToString();
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedAnswer"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just had a simple mistake in your code. You should data bind your `Tobetraced` property to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property instead of the `ComboBox.Text` property. Additionally, you could data bind an `int` property to the `ComboBoxItem.SelectedValue` property to get the numerical value that you put into the `ComboBoxItem.Tag` property... try this:

```
<ComboBox Width="60" Name="cmbTobetraced" Margin="0,15,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="White" SelectedValuePath="Tag" 
    SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" SelectedValue="{Binding IntProperty}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Tobetraced, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Yes" Tag="0" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="No" Tag="1" />
</ComboBox>
```

You might also find the following resource from MSDN useful:

[ComboBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx)

[How to: Use SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, and SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788714(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: your XAML is binding to something other than what you think - you might want to give your sample code a quick run through a test program...   :)

Comment: The bound value will be: `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Yes`, or `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: No`. I'm surprised that you're getting a different value. The behavior will differ if you're using an ItemsSource. However, the OP is not binding to an ItemsSource, so the binding value will not be what you expect it to be.

Comment: Yup, you're quite right about that, but it still shows which item was selected. However, as far as I am concerned, this answer is at the same level of complexity as the question, so I'm not trying to win any awards here. :)

Comment: Problem is still not solved . I uploaded the image. or can i use another control instead of combo box plz suggest me